# Consuming external APIs & automatically update access tokens (laravel application)

Tags: laravel, api, authorization, token

I would like to pull data from external APIs which are protected by bearer tokens.
At the moment I am doing something like this:

```
Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' =>'Bearer exampleToken'])->get('https://exampleAPI.com/data');
```

I am basically inserting the exampletoken manually into my laravel backend. For some external APIs the token has a limited life time.
Is there a way to automatically update the token in the background without requiring the user of my application to do anything?

Comment: Usually, in this type of scenario, when you first log into the service which provides the API, you get the token. But the API also comes with a refresh process. So when you first get the token, you can save it somewhere (in a DB, in the local storage, you name it), with a limit date, and before this limit date is reached, you send a request to the refresh endpoint to get a new token, and save it again... The best way to do it is through a CRON job if you send the requests from your backend.

Comment: Thank you, @Romain biard for your answer! But can you use the refresh process forever?

Comment: I think that it depends on the API you're working with, but usually, I would say yes, until the rules of the API change...